# Difference between Ext JS and Sencha

Tags: extjs

What is the difference between Ext JS and sencha is ext js 4.0 reverse compatible with ext js 3.4 ?

---

As per i have searched on web i found that merger of Ext JS with JQTouch formed sencha any guesses ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, Sencha did not merge with JQTouch.

Ext renamed to Sencha to better reflect that they were not just doing a single framework anymore, ExtJS, but a whole suite of tools including Sencha Touch.

As for compatibility, there were significant changes between ExtJS 3 and ExtJS 4 so they aren't directly compatible. If I recall there was a compatibility layer developed but I haven't used it and it wasn't meant to be a long term solution.

Answer (score 12):

Sencha is the company. It has several products. The two most popular at the moment are:

1) Ext JS - Framework for building client side apps for desktop.

2) Sencha Touch - Framework for building client side apps for mobile.